# Unable to send email using shared mailbox from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have about 35 files that I run daily, all of which send their own email to a different distribution list, depending on which report is being sent, and all from a shared email account which has been added to my Outlook. I have 2 files that, for some odd reason, will not send from the shared email account I need to use.

**Edit: To clarify, the code runs to completion, and I can see the email open and disappear quickly, as if the email DID send. But nothing sends and no email shows in that account's sent items.

I have added the Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library in my references, and all files are essentially using the same code:

```
Public Sub sendEmail()
    Dim OutLookApp As Object, oAccount As Outlook.Account
    Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
    
    Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
    For i = 1 To Outlook.Application.Session.Accounts.Count
        Set oAccount = OutLookApp.Session.Accounts.Item(i)
        If oAccount = "notmypersonalaccount@xxx.com" Then Exit For
    Next

    With OutLookMailItem
        Set .SendUsingAccount = OutLookApp.Session.Accounts.Item(i)
        .To = "user1; user2; user3; user4; user5; " _
        & "user6; user7; user8; user9; user10; user11; " _
        & "user12; user13; user14; user15; user16; " _
        & "user17; user18; user19; user20; user21; user22"
        .CC = "user23; user24; user25"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Queue Inquiry for " & Format(Now, "m/d/yyyy") & ":"
        .Display
        .HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Cambria>Good Morning, " & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
        "Please follow the link below to view the Queue Inquiry Report for " & Format(Now, "m/d/yyyy") _
        & ". Below are the queue listings applicable for each area. This report will show you the volume in each queue and is sorted by oldest referral date (to help manage SLAs/Production)." _
        & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Fraud Queues" & "<br>" & "-   JPF" & "<br>" & "-   PFR" & "<br>" & "<br>" _
        & "C/S Back Office" & "<br>" & "-   LBX" & "<br>" & "-   SCK" & "<br>" & "-   WSN" & "<br>" & "-   TCR" & "<br>" & "-   FIC" & "<br>" & "<br>" _
        & "Dispute Resolution" & "<br>" & "-   CS1" & "<br>" & "-   APP" & "<br>" & "-   RDP" & "<br>" & "-   RTV" & "<br>" & "<br>" _
        & "Credit Bureau Disputes" & "<br>" & "-   CBD" & "<br>" & "<br>" _
        & "Credit Back Office" & "<br>" & "-   LTQ" & "<br>" & "<br>" _
        & "Collections" & "<br>" & "-   MGR" & "<br>" & "<br>" _
        & "Bankruptcy" & "<br>" & "-   LD7" & "<br>" & "-   MM4" & "<br>" & "<br>" _
        & "<a href=""https://xxxx.xx.com/xxxx/xx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx xxxxx/"">xxxxx xxxxx</a></BODY>" & .HTMLBody
        .Send
    End With
End Sub
```

What I don't get is that this file was working yesterday, before I added 6 new people to the distro list, user17 through user22. If I comment out the `.SendUsingAccount = OutLookApp.Session.Accounts.Item(i)` I am able to send using my email account.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Some changes that may make the code more reliable.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub sendEmail()

    Dim OutLookApp As Object
    Dim oAccount As Outlook.account
    Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
    
    Dim srchAccount As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim foundFlag As Boolean
    
    Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    srchAccount = "notmypersonalaccount@xxx.com"
    
    For i = 1 To Session.Accounts.Count
        Set oAccount = Session.Accounts.Item(i)
        Debug.Print oAccount
        
        If oAccount = srchAccount Then
            foundFlag = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    If foundFlag = True Then

        With OutLookMailItem
        
            Set .SendUsingAccount = oAccount
            
            ' without a subsequent .Send you can see the mail
            .Display
                        
        End With
        
    Else
    
        MsgBox srchAccount & " not found."
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```

To remove Excel from possible causes.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub sendEmail_NotFromExcel()

    Dim oAccount As account
    Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
    
    Dim srchAccount As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim foundFlag As Boolean
    
    Set OutLookMailItem = CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    srchAccount = "notmypersonalaccount@xxx.com"
    
    For i = 1 To Session.Accounts.count
        Set oAccount = Session.Accounts.Item(i)
        Debug.Print oAccount
        
        If oAccount = srchAccount Then
            foundFlag = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    If foundFlag = True Then

        With OutLookMailItem
        
            Set .SendUsingAccount = oAccount
            
            .Display
                        
        End With
        
    Else
    
        MsgBox srchAccount & " not found."
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, a no-go. Again, I was able to see the email, but as soon as I clicked on Send, it just disappeared and didn't send. Not in Drafts, Outbox or Sent Items, either.

Comment: Save the displayed mail.  Without closing, find the draft and see if allowed to send.